# eclipse search replace regular expression iteration

Tags: xml, regex, expression

I am wanting to replace

`step="1" step="2" step="5" step="33"`

with the following

`step="1" step="2" step="3" step="4"`

I would like the replaced numbers to correct its iteration by 1.

So far for the find I have:

`step="\d"`

which works fine.
What can I use for the replace?

Comment: Unfortunately I think that's impossible unless you find a "callback" that matches a digit and increment it.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using `ant` and have included `ant-contrib` in your project..
you may use the `<math>` task to increment the value of a `var`.

assuming `${STEP_STRING}` = `step="1" step="2" step="5" step="33"`.
to generate `${NEW_STRING}` = `step="1" step="2" step="3" step="4"`

```
<var name="ctr" value="1"/>
<var name="ctr_str" value="step"/>
<var name="NEW_STRING" value=""/>

<for list="${STEP_STRING}" delimiter="${ctr_str}" param="str">
   <sequential>          
      <condition property="true">
          <matches string="@{str}" pattern="=&quot;\d&quot;"/>
      </condition>
      <if><isset property="true"/>
          <then>
             <propertyregex property="xx" input="@{str}" regexp="(=&quot;)\d(&quot;)" replace="\1${ctr}\2" override="true"/>
             <var name="NEW_STRING" value="${NEW_STRING} ${ctr_str}${xx}"/>
             <math result="ctr" operand1="${ctr}" operand2="1" operation="+" datatype="int" />
          </then>
      </if>
   </sequential>
</for>
<echo>${NEW_STRING}</echo>
```

---

i think this will generate the required String, *though i haven't tested it*, but it **builds a new string** instead of **replacing the previous String** (which you were looking for). replacement gets complicated in picking the `Nth occurrence of`**`="\d"`**.
i think you'll need a custom `<scriptdef>` for this task, which i'll try to write in the meantime.